# Need help getting information out of a .txt file, but only if the entered word exists already, using Python

Tags: python, file, text, extract

So I basically need to check whether the user's name exists in the .txt file. If it does, it needs to print the line that contains the name. If it doesn't, it needs to add the name.

So I've gotten as far as to copy the name to the .txt file, but it will also write the name if it exists already. Which it's not supposed to do.

This is the current code I have:

```
f = open("list_users.txt", "a+")
name = input('Enter your username: ')
if name in f:
    print('true')
else:
    f.write(name)
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

I know it's pretty basic, but I can't seem to get any further than this. I have no idea how to get the information out of the file, I can't even check if it exists already.

Comment: Pick one from [`[python] how to read file`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+how+to+read+file)

Answer (score 2):

this code doesn't read the file it is just opening it

```
name = input('Enter your username: ')
with open('list_users.txt', 'a+') as f:
    users = f.read()
    if name in users:
        print('true')
    else:
       f.write(naam)
       f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line is the issue.

```
if name in f:
```

Here you are checking if the `name` is in `file object' instead of checking it in lines.

Change the code like this.

```
name = input('Enter your username: ')
with open("list_users.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if name in line:
            print('true')
            break

    f.write(name + '\n')
```